# Attachment file name is incorrect

Tags: android

I am creating app in android in which i am sending Email with attachment. Email sending code is working fine but issue is that file which i receive on Email has wrong name. File name is concatenated with path name like i am creating file with name abc.csv and in mail i am receiving it as **_mnt_sdcard_MyTest_abc.csv**. Here is the code please suggest how to fix this.

```
 File   folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator
                 + getString(R.string.app_name));
   Mail m = new Mail("abc@gmail.com", "000000"); 
      String[] toArr = MailTo;
      m.setTo(toArr); 
      m.setFrom("abc@gmail.com"); 
      m.setSubject(Subject); 
      m.setBody(Body); 
      try { 
           m.addAttachment(folder+"/"+filename); 
          if(m.send()) {
              result= true;
        } else { 
            result= false;
        } 
      } catch(Exception e) { 
       Log.e("MailApp", "Could not send email", e); 
      } 
      return result;
```

Comment: so the class `Mail` is from which library or self implemented? What does the `addAttachment()` method does in detail (show some code?)?

Comment: @WarrenFaith: This is a library i am using for sending mail

Comment: Great, just don't tell us which library you are using. Stop providing information so that other users might find this via google... (who ever find irony, keep it...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cheange this line

```
File   folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator
                 + getResources().getString(R.string.app_name));
```

to make sure your file name is correct print log like below:

```
Log.e("FILENAME----->",""+folder.toString());
```